# How to trim Array items in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, trim

my array looks like this:

```
myArray = [a (1), b (22), c (34), d (6)]
```

Is there any way i can get only the alphabets of the array like:

```
myTrimmedArray = [a, b, c, d]
```

If I can get each elemnts of arrray trim it and then append it in a new array also works fine for me. But is that possible?

Comment: When you say `myArray = [a1, b22, c34, d6]`, do you mean `myArray = ["a1", "b22", "c34", "d6"]`?

Comment: no. just [a1, b22, c34, d6]

Comment: Are `a1`, `b22` then variables or other symbols you've defined?

Comment: Like [a(1),  b(22), c(34), d(6)]

Comment: Can you please show us the code where `a1` or `a(1)` is defined?

Comment: Am getting it from parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arrayCount = myArray.count
var i: Int
    for(i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++){
        var name = myArray[i] as String
        var myStringArr = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        var arrayValue = myStringArr[0]
        self.myTirimmedArray.append(arrayValue)   //Output: myTrimmedArray = [a, b, c, d]
    }
```

In this instaed of `componentsSeparatedByString` I could use `NSCharacterSet` But this thing worked for my requirements

Comment: Please look at the comments of Question. myArray is [a (1), b (22), c (34), d (6)]. I questioned it as a general. So i am trimming the first component and saving it as new array

Comment: Ah, so the contents of your array is indeed strings, with the values "a (1)", "b (22)".. etc. You should edit your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

To trim the digits off the ends of each string:

```
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
let myTrimmedArray = myArray.map( { $0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(digits) } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var myArray = ["a1", "b22", "c34", "d6"]
var myTrimmedArray = [String]()

for i in myArray{

    let temp = "\(Array(i)[0])"
    myTrimmedArray.append(temp)
}

myTrimmedArray         //["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myArray = ["a (1)", "b (22)", "c (34)", "d (6)"]
let myTrimmedArray = myArray.map{Array($0).first!}

println(myTrimmedArray)   // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```